# Excel Power Query: querying an API with JSON Body. How to send as list and not as string?

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

I want to query an API via Excel Power Query so I can use it in my Excel Sheet. The API expects data in the following format as a JSON:

```json
[
  "API Key",
  {
    "Location": ["value1"],
    "Measurements": [2],
    "Start": "value"
  }
]
```

I am currently using the following script to query the API:

```
let
    jsonBody = Json.FromValue("
    [
        ""APIKEY"",
        {
            ""Location"":""MyCity"",
            ""Measurements"":2,
            ""Start"":""-2d""
        }
    ]
    "),

    apiUrl = "URL.com/query",

    customHeaders = [#"Content-type" = "application/json"],

    source = Web.Contents(apiUrl, [
        Headers = customHeaders,
        Content = jsonBody,
        ManualStatusHandling = {400}
    ]),
    response = if Value.Metadata(source)[Response.Status] = 200 then Json.Document(source) else error Text.FromBinary(source)
in
    response
```

At my server, the query arrives but is interpreted as a string and not as a list in a JSON.

I already tried removing the "" encasing the JSON, but Excel does not accept this and gives me an error regarding missing brackets after the API Key, which does not really make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something similar to this:

```
jsonBody = Text.FromBinary(Json.FromValue(
[
    APIKEY=
    {
        "Location:MyCity",
        "Measurements:2",
        "Start:-2d"
    }
]
)),
```

You'd have to adjust based on sending/not sending quotes, etc.